# Trouble Connecting To DynamoDB Locally with ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm attempting to save form submissions to a DynamoDB table, however, I'm running into issues connecting locally. I'm running DynamoDB locally for now, but I would later like to move it back to a normal DDB instance accessible from Elastic Beanstalk.

I've downloaded and unzipped `dynamodb-local` into a directory and ran the `java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb`
 command, ensuring that I'm in the appropriate directory. When I run the command I get this:

```
    Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
    Port:   8000
    InMemory:       false
    DbPath: null
    SharedDb:       true
    shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
    CorsParams:     *
```

At this point I attempt to submit a form to my POST endpoint in `app.js`, but I get this repeating error in the terminal I'm running DynamoDB local in:

```
    Jan 12, 2019 1:24:25 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
    WARNING: [sqlite] cannot open DB[1]: 
    com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\cygwin64\home\Administrator\dynamodb_local_latest\DynamoDBLocal_lib\sqlite4java-win32-x64.dll: Access is denied
    Jan 12, 2019 1:24:25 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
    SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[shared-local-instance.db]: error running job queue
    com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\cygwin64\home\Administrator\dynamodb_local_latest\DynamoDBLocal_lib\sqlite4java-win32-x64.dll: Access is denied
        at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:97)
        at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open0(SQLiteConnection.java:1441)
        at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:282)
        at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:293)
        at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.openConnection(SQLiteQueue.java:464)
        at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.queueFunction(SQLiteQueue.java:641)
        at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.runQueue(SQLiteQueue.java:623)
        at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.access$000(SQLiteQueue.java:77)
        at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue$1.run(SQLiteQueue.java:205)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\cygwin64\home\Administrator\dynamodb_local_latest\DynamoDBLocal_lib\sqlite4java-win32-x64.dll: Access is denied
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.tryLoadFromPath(Internal.java:340)
        at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.loadLibraryX(Internal.java:117)
        at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:95)
        ... 9 more
```

In the terminal that I'm running the cluster of Node workers I'm getting the following error output from each worker (8) and then a DDB error:

```
    Failed to create table in DB.
     { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
        at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
        at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:14)
      message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000',
      code: 'NetworkingError',
      errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 8000,
      region: 'us-west-2',
      hostname: 'localhost',
      retryable: true,
      time: 2019-01-12T20:31:00.742Z }
    DDB Error: NetworkingError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
```

I promise I'm finishing this up. Here's my code for creating the DDB table (I pass `const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB()` as the parameter from `app.js`):

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

    function createDDBTable(ddb, tableName) {
        // console.log('ddb:\n',ddb);
        const tableParams = {
            AttributeDefinitions: [
                {
                    AttributeName: 'email',
                    AttributeType: 'S'
                },
                {
                    AttributeName: 'id',
                    AttributeType: 'S'
                }
            ],
            KeySchema: [
               {
                AttributeName: 'email',
                KeyType: 'HASH'
               },
               {
                    AttributeName: 'id',
                    KeyType: 'RANGE'
               }
            ],
            ProvisionedThroughput: {
                ReadCapacityUnits: 8,
                WriteCapacityUnits: 8
            },
            TableName: tableName,
            StreamSpecification: {
                StreamEnabled: false
            }
        };
        ddb.createTable(tableParams, (err, data) => {
            if(err) console.error('Failed to create table in DB.\n', err);
            else console.log('Success creating table!', data);
        })
    }
    module.exports = createDDBTable;
```

I'm at a loss for where I'm going wrong. All of my validation and endpoints work, however, when it comes time to create a table my code keeps me stumbling through errors. I also have a feeling I may need to adjust my `options.config` file a bit, but I'm not sure how to format that. Thanks in advance for any help! I tried to be thorough about my issue, but let me know if I can expand on anything else.

Comment: Have you tried connecting with just the AWS CLI? Just to make sure dynamodb-local is running correctly and eliminate the SDK from the mix.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried listing my tables and it throws the error I posted above (the SQLite related Git Bash terminal error). Seems to narrow down the issue to an inability to execute anything in the `DynamoDBLocal_lib` directory, but that's just my new assumption. Still getting the `ERRCONREFUSED`, `NetworkingError`.

Comment: I'm hoping to keep the SDK, since I'm moving this back onto DynamoDB to access from Elastic Beanstalk. I don't want to commit to Local, if that's an actual concern come time to move to production (make scripts?). Still learning a lot of AWS.

Comment: @Kirk I'm getting the same error when running on GitLab CI, locally works perfectly fine. I'm using `dynamodb-local` version `0.0.25`. I've added a listener to the child process with `child.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()));` and `child.stderr.on('data', data => console.error('ERROR!', data.toString()));` but it only seems to print the configuration details...

Comment: did u find any solution?

Answer (score 4):

instead of http://localhost:port use your computer IP. it will work.
ex: http://xxx.yy.zz.aaa:port   <--your computer IP

Comment: this solved my issue, but how should I go about not having to change the config every time the network connection changes? I'm new to Docker, so most likely I'm missing something...